# Access Denied when executing a CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, caml-query, provider-hosted-app

I am running a SharePoint Online provider-hosted app, and via CSOM, I am loading the contents of a list with the following code:

`var items = List.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
_clientContext.Load(items);
_clientContext.ExecuteQueryAutoBackOff();`

By using a `ClientContext` with a Bearer Token – ie. using the app model – the request fails. It doesn't matter what user is logged in. I can load properties of the list successfully eg. `List.Title`. Only CAML queries fail.

I am certain that I have access to this list. Additionally:

- When constructing a `ClientContext` using a `SharePointOnlineCredential` object (specifying a username and password explicitly), the request succeeds.
- The same user can view items in the browser.
- All other lists, which have the EXACT SAME security permissions (ie. inheriting), return results successfully.
- Breaking inheritance and explicitly assigning Full Control to Everyone makes no difference.
- It was working previously, but I'm not sure at what point it stopped working. I don't think any changes have been made to either the code or the list.

What could be different about this list that causes Access Denied?

Comment: does the list has more than 5000 items?

Comment: Nope, about 20.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was SharePoint behaviour. Here are the steps to reproduce:

- Go into Term Store Management and create a custom termset.
- Create a new site field based on that termset.
- Add the field to the list. Add some list items with values from the termset.
- Go into Term Store Management, edit the termset, and select `Use this Term Set for Site Navigation`.

At this point, attempting to query the list items via an app will result in Access Denied. Attempting to query the list items via any other mechanism is successful.

I believe this is a bug with either SharePoint or SharePoint Online only.